# Eslint expected indentation of 1 tab but found 4 spaces error

Tags: node.js, config, eslint

I am using VScode with latest version of Eslint. It is my first time using a linter.

I keep getting this linting error when using a tab as indentation:

**severity: 'Error'
message: 'Expected indentation of 1 tab but found 4 spaces. (indent)'
at: '4,5'
source: 'eslint'**

Here is my config file

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
},
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"rules": {
    "indent": [
        "error",
        "tab"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "unix"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        "error",
        "single"
    ],
    "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
    ]
}
}
```

I don't understand why this error is being thrown as I indicated tabs for indentation. It is obviously calculating my 1 tab as 4 spaced but I don't understand why it is doing that when I am pressing tab for indentation.

**update:** The reason is because in VScode using <kbd>ctrl + shift + i</kbd> to beautify code will actually use spaces and not tabs. That is the reason.

Answer (score 66):

Try to disable **indent** inside **.eslintrc.js** file

```
rules: {
   'indent': 'off'
}
```

this works fine for me

Comment: In case you have `.eslintrc.json`: `"rules": {"indent":"off"}` with double quotes.

Answer (score 52):

In VSCODE, go to menu:

`File / Preferences / Settings` then `Text Editor` (or just search for 'tab' in the search settings box)

Then remove the tick from the following settings:

- `Insert Spaces`
- `Detect Indentation`

Also to auto format the document with the default VSCode keyboard shortcut use:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Comment: In VS Code this is the correct answer, thanks !

Answer (score 30):

If you use both `eslint` and `prettier`, don't disable indent by using `{'indent': 'off'}` in rules object. To ensure the consistency of your code style, you have to use this rule.

**Solution:**

This issue is probably happened because of eslint & prettier conflict.
Try to play with different options of eslint in `.eslintrc` file.

If you hover the error lines in vsCode, at the end of error description you can click on that link to see eslint docs.

For example, in case of `indent` docs is in this link:

[Eslint Indent Docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent)

For me, error resolved by adding this line (for ternary expressions):

```
...
rules: {
    indent: [
  'error',
  2,
  {
    SwitchCase: 1,
    ignoredNodes: ['ConditionalExpression'], <-- I add this line
  },
],
...
```

You can also try `flatTernaryExpressions` or `offsetTernaryExpressions` for ternary expressions.

Comment: This is the correct answer for those who are having this problem when using `switch case`

Answer (score 11):

You can automaticaly fix the problems with

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

Answer (score 7):

I used VScode to solve this problem. All you have to do is hold the mouse over the part where there is an error.
[image]

and...
[image]

Comment: Maybe this comes from a extension you are using? I get: "No quick fixes available"

Comment: @Jesper Hustad, You can use eslint plugin to fix the issue. All though, this will not fix the issues in the build or in the pipeline for existing files

Comment: To be able to do this the extension called ESLint must be installed. But this trick of using the mouse to fix the error does work.

Answer (score 4):

There was a conflict between plugins in my example. I'm using `eslint` version `8.24.0`. To fix, i just removed the rule `plugin:prettier/recommended` and added `prettier` at last position from `extends` as explained in `eslint-config-prettier` documentation. See: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#arrow-body-style-and-prefer-arrow-callback

Before:

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended",
  ]
```

After:

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Wee, that exactly what it says. You have in your config "indent": [ "error", "tab" ], So it expects tab as indent. But found in your file 4 spaces. Remove spaces and put tab in you file

Comment: I don't user 4 spaces when i indent though, I use a tab so why is it detecting 4 spaces? and if I remove and hit tab again the problem is not solved

Comment: Found out the reason, its beacause in VSCODE when you do ctrl shift + i to beautify code it actually uses 4 spaces and not tabs. That is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

change `"editor.tabSize": 4`
to `"editor.tabSize": 2` in VS Code Settings

Comment: Editor: Detect Indentation is off, then  "editor.tabSize": 2

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved with this code:

```
rules: {
    ...
    indent: [2, "tab"],
    "no-tabs": 0,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## If you are using VSCODE follow the next steps.

1. Access the settings by clicking: **code > preferences > settings**, as shown in the following image.

[image]

2. In the settings, click: *Text Editor* after that, uncheck the *Insert Space* option and the *Detect Indentation* option as shown in the following image.

[image]

3. Restart VSCODE and your dev server.

Answer (score 1):

In file

```
settings.json
```

remove this line if have:

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
```

eslint conflict with prettier

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I solved my problem with documentation. Instead of disabling eslint indent, you can add it as shown in the documentation.

[Docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent)

Simple:

```
rules: {
  indent: ['error', 2, { "MemberExpression": 1 }],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For individual files, we can utilize the following comment at the top of the page. This will disable eslint check for that particular file with respect to the indent

Just TypeScript

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/indent */
```

For JavaScript

```
/* eslint-disable indent */
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me, if error is coming then just solve it line by line simply in your code,
like :
1.)Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 8 -> then put only 2 spaces from the starting of the line
2.)Unexpected tab character -> don't use tabs, use spaces
3.)Trailing spaces not allowed -> don't give any spaces after lines end.
4.)Missing space before value for key 'name' -> put 1 space after ":" in object value
5.)A space is required after ',' -> put 1 space after "," in parameter of the function
6.)Opening curly brace does not appear on the same line as controlling statement -> just put the opening curly brace where function starts in the same line
7.)Closing curly brace should be on the same line as opening curly brace or on the line after the previous block -> put the closing curly brace just below where the function starts.

Answer (score -10):

Please add the below comment at the first line of the JS file that you are customizing.

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing more information on your solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by not posting it in the first place. Installing a linter in order to disable it is not a bright thing to do.

Comment: Your answer does not help.

Comment: This is not an good answer this is just hack which can get anyone fired 