# Why does this ES lint error pop up again after fixing it?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, eslint

i'm trying to deploy a cloud function to firebase using the 'firebase deploy --only functions' command, but them I keep getting this error:

> 42:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6  indent
> 43:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6  indent
> 44:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6  indent
> 44:12  error  Missing trailing comma

I copied it in, searched google and tried many different things such as changing my vs code settings, reinstalling firebase command tools, and installing prettier as well. Once I installed prettier, I was able to clean up a lot of the error, but now it's these four that I'm getting from this set of code. How can I work around this or fix it to get my function to deploy to the firebase console?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createStripeCheckout = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Stripe init
  const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "http://localhost:5500/success",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:5500/cancel",
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["US"],
    },
    line_items: [
      {
        quantity: 1,
        price_data: {
          currency: "usd",
          unit_amount: 100 * 100, // 10000 = 100 USD
          product_data: {
            name: "sessionType",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return {
    id: session.id,
  };
});

exports.stripeWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.token);
  let event;

  try {
    const whSec = functions.config().stripe.payments_webhook_secret;
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.rawBody,
      req.headers["stripe-signature"],
      whSec,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("⚠️ Webhook signature verification failed.");
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }

  const dataObject = event.data.object;

  await admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc().set({
    checkoutSessionId: dataObject.id,
    paymentStatus: dataObject.payment_status,
    shippingInfo: dataObject.shipping,
    amountTotal: dataObject.amount_total,
  });

  return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301014/eslint-expected-indentation-of-1-tab-but-found-4-spaces-error)? It clearly tells you don't have proper indentation and some missing trailing commas e.g. after `whSec` line. You can use this [playground](https://eslint.org/play/) to see what might be causing issues with your ESLint rules.

Comment: The code you posted is only 27 lines long. Which are lines 42 through 44?

Comment: Now it's working. At first it told me to add a comma after the 'whSec' line but then when I added the indentation rule it fixed it. Thank you very much!